# How to assign one property as equal to other in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a class, that I later use in angular component.

```
export class MyClass {

  prop: string;

  constructor(val){
    this.prop = val;
  }

  public getLength(str: string): number {
    return str.length;
  }
}
```

The component:

```
@Component(...)
export class MyComponent implements OnInit{

  public prop1: MyClass;
  public prop2: MyClass;

  constructor(private myService: MyService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myService.getValue().subscribe(val => {
      this.prop1 = val;
      this.prop2 = val
    });
  }

  public onResetEvent(): void {
    this.prop1 = this.prop2; 
  }

  ....

}
```

When component works value of this.prop1 changes and from time to time I need to reset value of this.value1 to initial value (this.prop2 exists only for this one).

I try to use onResetEvent() function but it works only at first time (I reset this.prop1), but doesn't happen next times. Prop2 changes if prop1 changes.

How to solve my task?

Comment: Define “doesn’t work”. My *guess* is that you intend to restore the initial value—but prop2 is a *reference* to the original object, not a *copy*, so as prop1 changes so does what prop2 references, because they both reference the *same object*.

Comment: Dave Newton, seems exactly as you wrote. After the first successful reset, next times nothing happens and prop2 changes when prop1 changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cloneDeep()` method of [lodash-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es) for angular.

```js
  import * as lodash from 'lodash-es';
  .
  .
  .
  public onResetEvent(): void {
    this.prop1 = lodash.cloneDeep(this.prop2); 
  }
```